# The Four Categories of Pralaya (Annihilation) and how it can be stopped?

Tags: puranas, universe

What are the four categories of Universal Annihilation? There are four kinds of annihilation  (constant, occasional, material and final) and how it can be stopped?

Comment: SB 12.4 describes about four categories of annihilation. But I don't know how the universal annihilation can be stopped.

Comment: why would you think it can be stopped?

Comment: Annihilation is part of nature. Where there is a creation, there will be annihilation of that creation also. Everything is used to create by Brahma for certain amount of time only. When that time being over then He/She/It has to be annihilated. So that new creation can take place of prev. creation.

Comment: @Rishabh-You have told about the chain process. When it will be stopped?

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda-Material pleasure will never end in humans. How there will be a control or what is the point where it will get stopped?

Answer (score 1):

> Srimad Bagavatham Canto 12.4 describes the four kinds of annihilation
>   (constant, occasional, material and final) and the chanting of the
>   holy name of Lord Hari, which is the only means of stopping the cycle
>   of material life. One thousand cycles of four ages constitute one day 
>   of Brahmā, and each day of Brahmā, called a kalpa, contains within it 
>   the lifetimes of fourteen Manus. The duration of Brahmā’s night is the
>   same as that of his day. During his night Brahmā sleeps, and the three
>   planetary systems meet destruction; this is the naimittika, or 
>   occasional, annihilation. When Brahmā’s life span of one hundred years
>   is finished, there occurs the prākṛtika, or total material,
>   annihilation.
>
> At that time the seven elements of material nature,> beginning with
>   the mahat, and the entire universal egg composed of them are
>   destroyed. When a person achieves knowledge of the Absolute, he
>   understands factual reality. He perceives the entire created >
>   universe as separate from the Absolute and therefore unreal. That is 
>   called the ātyantika, or final, annihilation (liberation).
>
> At every  moment time invisibly transforms the bodies of all created
>   beings and all other manifestations of matter. This process of
>   transformation causes the living entity to undergo the constant
>   annihilation of birth and death. Those possessed of subtle vision
>   state that all creatures, including Brahmā himself, are always subject
>   to generation and annihilation. Material life means subjugation to
>   birth and death, or generation and annihilation. The only boat
>   suitable for crossing the ocean of material existence, which is
>   otherwise impossible to cross, is the boat of submissive hearing of
>   the nectarean pastimes of the Supreme Personality of Godhead.

Answer (score 1):

1. Nitya - people born and die everyday
2. Naimittika - after 1 kalpa (daytime) of Brahma, 3 worlds, including earth are destroyed
3. Prakrita - after 1 lifetime of Brahma, entire 14 worlds dissolved into Prakriti
4. Atyantika - soul gets Moksha